# What does "saw" mean in "saw service"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I found this sentence in the dictionary under the *service* entry.

> He saw service in North Africa.

Because it's a bilingual dictionary, I know it means *he has served in military in North Africa* in English. But what does *saw* mean here? I looked it up in the dictionary but still not sure what it means here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's one of the meanings of *see* - to experience.

[Merriam-Webster *see*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/see)

> 3 c : to have experience of : undergo
> *see army service*

[American Heritage Dictionary *see*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=see)

> 5.a. To know through firsthand experience; undergo or experience:
> *He saw service in the navy. She has seen many changes in her lifetime.*